# Duplicating attribute in Magento

Tags: attributes, magento, magento-1.4

What would be the proper way in Magento v1.4 to programmatically duplicate a (product) attribute? I'm fairly new to Magento and trying some things out to get to know it :)

I've so far come up with the following,

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($id_of_attribute_to_copy);
$data = $attribute->getData();
$data['attribute_id'] = '';
$data['attribute_code'] = 'new_attribute_name';
$attribute->setData($data);
$attribute->save();
```

but attributes seem to exist as a relation between two main tables, `eav_attribute` and `catalog_eav_attribute`. When I execute the code, only an entry for `catalog_eav_attribute` is created resulting in a Foreign Key error for `eav_attribute` (in which a new record doesn't yet exist). Hope someone can help.

Comment: best way to find out is to open up some setup files from core models to see what it takes to describe a attribute or make a print_r($attribute->getData()); to see the possible values or use addData() instead of setData()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some resources on the typical way of creating attributes.

[Advanced ORM - Part 7](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-7-advanced-orm-entity-attribute-value)
[Installing custom attributes with your module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/installing_custom_attributes_with_your_module)

Comment: This.  You need to configure your Magento system to use and know about the additional attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Not works links from last comment but i think need:

```
$mainEavAttribute = [logic..]
$eavSetup->addAttribute(Product::ENTITY,'new_attribute',$mainEavAttribute);
```